# Weird IP addresses found in logs

Tags: networking, ip, ip-camera

I'm reviewing some logs of cameras in a small office and I see, besides the access from different private ips from devices within the network a lot of entries from IP addreeses that are, according to what I have found, SHARED-ADDRESS-SPACE-RFCTBD-IANA-RESERVED. Further checking in https://ipinfo.io/ tells me that the IP address is categorized as "bogon", https://ipinfo.io/bogon

Any idea of what it means? 
Thanks

Miles

Comment: What are the first two octets of the address on your router's WAN interface? Your ISP could be using CGN. The Shared address space is used inside ISP networks (normally only for residential networks) because the RIRs have run out of IPv4 addresses to assign to the ISPs.

Answer (score 0):

Per [rfc6598](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6598), (IANA-Reserved IPv4 Prefix for Shared Address Space) addresses in this range may use Carrier-Grade NAT (CGN). The name almost explains itself. RIR reserved these addresses for ISPs to NAT to the subscriber.

Why you are seeing this isn't clear based on your description. I guess, if the ISP setup these cameras, they may used these addresses to update the cameras.